# Average of irrational flow on the torus

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, fourier-analysis, ergodic-theory

Let $$F(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\sin(2\pi x) - \sin(2\pi y)}}$$
defined on $\mathbb{T}^2$. Here $\mathbb{T}^2 = \mathbb{R}^2/ \mathbb{Z}^2$ is the 2-torus. How can I show that
$$ \lim_{T\longrightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T F(x,\sqrt{2}x)\;dx = \iint_{[0,1]^2} F(x,y)\;dxdy?$$
What can we say about the rate of convergence? Say $\frac{1}{T^\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

Comment: As this function is Riemann integrable (and this is important), the equidistribution theorem (which follows from unique-ergodicity of the flow) is applicable here as well.

The quantitative estimate is essentially the same for say $C^{\infty}_{c}$ functions, as one may take the Fourier expansion here as well. One need to be a bit careful, as the Fourier inversion might be slightly weird near the singularity, but you can control that part yourself with the square-root singularity + some diophantine properties of the square root (BA).

Comment: Can you explain more or provide some references? I really want to handle this rigorously. Truly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need a fancy reference here, this is very easy to do by hand (and definitely not suitable for a MO question). The only slightly non-trivial thing is that the equidistribution theorem holds for Riemann integrable functions as well, but that follows from density + continuity.  Do you know how to deduce quantitative equidistribution results for nicer functions? Say your favorite trigonometrical polynomial?

Comment: The thing is by Riemann integrable the function has to be bounded, is that right? This function $F$ is not bounded, I cannot find a continuous function that approximate $F$ from above to carry out the argument (left behind the bound for quantitative part).

Comment: Of course for nicer function, say $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2)$ I can get a rate $C/T$ where $C$ depends on some Sobolev norm of $F$, but it doesn't help (at least in my way) to get the result since the constant may blow up when getting closer to $F$.

Comment: it has a square root singularity, that's the important thing (and obviously, you don't actually hit the singularity by the orbit, otherwise the average blows up). I doubt you can get exactly $O(T^{-1})$, but the method is the same as for a nice function, cut down the singularity by a small ball or so of width $W$ say. Outside of $W$, you approximate $f$ (say by Fejer kernel trick or so) and deduce the equidistribution result. Inside the ball, for a large but fixed $T$, you will see about NUM lines, which are separated from each other and from the singularity (here comes the BA

Comment: assumption, you might need Roth's theorem or use the subspace theorem), hence you may estimate the part of the average there by $NUM*W*(\epsilon)^{-1/2}$, where epsilon depends on the BA assumption or so. Now you need to see the dependence of $NUM$ in $W$, the dependence of $\epsilon$ in $W$, and optimize that with the equidistribution rate to get something effective (note that the choice of $W$ effects the equidistribution rate, for example by enlarging the Sobolev norm, so you got yourself some optimization game to do).

Comment: Sorry but what are BA and NUM?

Comment: NUM (which depends on W and on T and $\sqrt(2)$) is the number of line segments you see inside this ball, BA is badly approximable.

Comment: @Asaf. Are you saying that the equidistribution theorem holds for all Riemann integrable functions (even unbounded ones)? I don't think this is true but maybe there is some special property related to $\sqrt{2}$ that makes it true. By the way, Roth theorem does not seem very easy to me.

Comment: @coudy, obviously such a thing does not hold in generality (i.e. just move your orbit so you hit a singularity in your sum), it will not even hold in a general uniquely ergodic system (if for example one have positive entropy, I'm pretty sure you can manufacture counter-example). This particular example deals with a particular system - Kronecker system (i.e. unipotent flow). The basic idea is easy - without singularities at all (assuming diophatnine condition on the slope, that's a must), you quantify that by looking at trigonometrical polyonmials, which essentially discretize the space.

Comment: The only step needed further is to truncate the function in the problematic cell of the sub-lattice, use the quantitative equidistribution for the rest, and try to handle this particular cell by hand, which would include data like how close is the piece of the orbit (of length T) to the singularity itself (which involves a diophatnine condition) and how much time this piece of orbits spends in the cell (+obviously the specific singularity type, which should relate to the diophantine condition somehow).